# calling startActivityForResult from Custom ViewGroup

Tags: android

I have a custom group view that extends from LinearLayout:

```
class MyCustomView extends LinearLayout {
    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        onCreateView(context);
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, int checkableId) {
        super(context);
        onCreateView(context);
    }

    private void onCreateView(Context context){
        View.inflate(context, R.id.my_custom_view, null);
    }
}
```

In that custom group view I have a button and when the user clicks that button I need to call an activity with startActivityForResult because I need the return from that activity.

But the LinearLayout doesn't implement the startActivityForResult neither the onActivityResult.

So my question is: how can I call startActivityForResult from "MyCustomView"?

Comment: You need to call `startActivityForResult` from the activity, where you are using `MyCustomView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you have two options:

1. Use `MyCustomView` in a class that extends one of flavors of `Activity`, `Fragment` or `FragmentActivity` and call `startActivityForResult()` from there.
2. Pass the instance of your activity to `MyCustomView` (possibly through the constructor) and use `instanceOfYourActivity.startActivityForResult()`. This, hovewere, could be unsafe and cause side effects (e.g., you may not be able to catch `onActivityResult()`).

Comment: I tried to use fragments, but nested fragments isn't supported yet and I don't want to instantiate the fragment programatically, so I will use your second option, the only problem is that the method onActivityResult have to be implemented in the Activity.

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 solutions for this that works for me. I don't know if the solutions are good :-)

Solution A:

1. The Customview is an inner Class of the Main Activity
2. The MainActivity has a method which starts the second activity:

   ```
   public void openSearchActivity(){

   Intent mySearchIntent = new Intent( this, SearchActivity.class);
   startActivityForResult(mySearchIntent, 0);
   ```

   }
3. In the ontouch method of the custom view call the MainActivity method ( openSearchActivity ):

Solution B :

1. In your Custom View add a Activity property which you set to the Main Activity during creation of the customView:

   ```
   Activity mainactivity;

   public void setMainactivity(Activity mainactivity) {
       this.mainactivity = mainactivity;
   }
   ```

.....

```
    myCustomView.setMainactivity(this);
```

1. start the activity in the onTouch :

   ```
               Intent mySearchIntent = new Intent( mainactivity, SearchActivity.class);
               mainactivity.startActivityForResult(mySearchIntent,1);
   ```