# implement a method startActivityForResult in a view

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I have a ListView and each item with two pictures and want you to click on one of them I read QR codes with zxing.

I get an error when invoking the method startActivityForResult and do not know which method could replace it or how. 
I leave some code:
MY HOLDER CLASS

```
public class ObrasHolder {
    public ImageView foto;
    public TextView num, iden, ubi,hombres,material,equipo;
    public RelativeLayout fondo;
    public TextView eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4;
    public TextView g1,g2,g3,g4;
    public ImageView cam,qr;
}
```

MY CUSTOM ADAPTER:

```
public class ObrasAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Obra> {
    public Context context;
    private ArrayList<Obra> datos;

    public void DisplayProjectListAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public ObrasAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Obra> datos) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_item, datos);
        this.context = context;
        this.datos = datos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View item = convertView;
        ObrasHolder holder;

        if (item == null) {
            item = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview_item,
                    null);

            holder = new ObrasHolder();
            holder.foto = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.imgAnimal);
            holder.num = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.numC);
            holder.iden = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.idenC);
            holder.ubi = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.ubiC);
            holder.hombres = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.homC);
            holder.material = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.matC);
            holder.eq1 = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.eq1);
            holder.eq2 = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.eq2);
            holder.eq3 = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.eq3);
            holder.eq4 = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.eq4);
            holder.g1 = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.g1);
            holder.g2 = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.g2);
            holder.g3 = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.g3);
            holder.g4 = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.g4);
            holder.fondo = (RelativeLayout) item.findViewById(R.id.fondobra);
            holder.cam = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.cam);
            holder.qr = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.qr);

            item.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder = (ObrasHolder) item.getTag();

        holder.qr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);   //Error because is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}     
            }
         });

        return item;
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
       if (requestCode == 0) {
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
             // Handle successful scan
          } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
             // Handle cancel
          }
       }
    }

}
```

Any idea to solve it?

i give an other erro too. In methdod onActivityResult.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the **Activity** holding the adapter:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
       if (requestCode == 0) {
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
             // Handle successful scan
          } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
             // Handle cancel
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hello thank you very much. That method've put in the class of my custom adapter in the end, you say it in the class of the holder?

Comment: Yes, in the context of the adapter.

Comment: i think i don't uderstand you ... you say this? `public ObrasAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Obra> datos) {
  super(context, R.layout.listview_item, datos);
  this.context = context; this.datos = datos;
  
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)`

Comment: No. You use ObrasAdapter as an adapter to a ListView, right? You should put your onActivityResult method in the activity that hosts this ListView.

Comment: thaks, this method (onActivityResult ) gives no errors but eclipse says the line startActivityForResult(intent, 0);  it's an error because: is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: Can you post your code? it seems you put it in the wrong place.

Comment: I've edited the post to make it look better anyway is this code: `holder.qr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
          
          Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
          intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
          startActivityForResult(intent, 0);        
         }
   });`

Comment: I have already put the code in the activity that has the listview

Comment: Ok, you should use the context to execute startActivityForResult.
Try context.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

Comment: i've tryed this but it says that it's a mistake too

Comment: Can you post what've you tried? Also, is it the same error?

Comment: i've tried this: `context.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);` and it says: is undefined for the type Context and it suggest me change to `context.startActivity(intent);` but it not works

Comment: Sorry, try this:
((Activity) context)..startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

Comment: import android.app.Activity;

Comment: now I get an error on execution: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN (has extras) }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1659)` I found this in the forum but do not quite understand what they mean: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970356/calling-startactivityforresult-from-custom-viewgroup)

Comment: All these issues really don't relate to your original question. I suggest you create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Its undefined because, the system is looking for the method in the `setOnClickListener`context. You should provide the global context to it. 
You have the context variable but that too is not sufficient you should try to wrap the context with the Activity type.

```
((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

This will do for you but just make sure when you pass context to constructor you pass it the activity context using `this` keyword.

Comment: thanks but it say: Activity cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: its stange, make sure you have this statement imported : import android.app.Activity;

Comment: now I get an error on execution:` android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN (has extras) } at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1659)`  I found this in the forum but do not quite understand what they mean: [link] (stackoverflow.com/questions/16970356/…)

Comment: Its not related now to your problem you posted. This is related to your intent. You are looking for an activity which is not installed in your phone or your app is not able to find it . Make sure you have this app installed to which you are directing your intent. You can download the latest zxing scan app here , https://github.com/zxing/zxing/releases